# `git fetch --depth=1 origin +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*` fails if no tags exist

Tags: git

How can I make `git fetch --depth=1 origin +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*` returns silently and not error when no tags exist?

I need to fetch a list of tags in CI to check whether the current commit has an associated tag. But running `actions/checkout@v2` in GitHub Actions has a default `fetch-depth` of 1 and it does not fetch tags. I need to fetch the tags manually. So after running this action I run `git fetch --depth=1 origin +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*`, but this fails when there are no tags. I don't want it to fail, I need it to silenty return and go on to the next step, which is `git describe --all --exact-match`. That command works even when there are no tags, which is the behavior I'm looking for.

Comment: This should be tagged [tag:github-actions] since what you *really* want is to make the action proceed, and then the answer is simple: add `|| true` to ignore any failure in `git fetch`. But with the current tagging, the answer is probably to add some refspecs that will succeed.